# Match a regex in vimscript and return it

Tags: php, regex, vim

Before I say what I'm attempting to do, I want to preface it with me being open to any/all solutions.

Basically I'm editing a PHP file.  We have a localization function in the class I'm editing that takes a key, similar to this:

```
$this->localize('SOME_KEY_HERE');
```

What I'm looking to do (in VIM) is create a keybinding that will determine what the localization value of that function call is, when the cursor is over that key.  I can get the key easily enough into a vimscript function.  My plan was then to just find the class name via regex (this doesn't need to be perfect) and then instantiate that class via :exec php -r and call the function.  So more or less, create a minimal script that would actually make the call.

Like I said, I can get the key isolated the way I want.  But trying to figure out the proper vimscript way to find the current class.  Basically I want the second word on the first line that matches /^class / in the current file, in a vimscript variable.  I've browsed some of the documentation but can't seem to get it to work.

Open to any/all suggestions on how to perform this operation.

Edit: To clarify, I can isolate the key I'm highlighting by doing something like:

```
noremap <leader>z :call DoSomething(expand("<cword>"))<CR>

function! DoSomething(l)
    let key = a:l
    echom key
endfunction
```

Comment: Will you share with us your start on the script where you are getting the key?

Comment: Edited the original to add an example of how i was planning on getting the locale key in a variable in a vimscript function.

Comment: can you make an example of input text, with `class` and so on. To me, the question is not clear enough. what did you mean `I want the second word on the first line that matches /^class /`? why does it have something to do with your `SOME_KEY_HERE`? what do you want to do?

Comment: Because I want to instantiate an object of the type of the class that I'm in, so I can run a bash script to actually create an instance of the object and ultimately call the localize() method on it, with the key I'm currently hovered over.  The second word of the first line matching ^class would be the class name of the current file, in the most likely scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of the current class with:

```
function! DoSomething(l)
    let key = a:l
    search('^class\s\zs\w\+\ze', 'b')
    let class = expand('<cword>')
    echo 'key: ' . key . ' class: ' . class
endfunction
```

You still need to deal with the position of the cursor.